# serverless - How to add multiple files to iamRoleStatements?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, serverless-framework

In my `serverless.yml` file, I want to be able to add `iamRoleStatements` from two differents files (this cannot change). So I tried doing it like this:

```
provider:
  iamRoleStatements: 
    - ${file(__environments.yml):dev.iamRoleStatements, ''}
    - ${file(custom.yml):provider.iamRoleStatements, ''}
```

Each of these files have an `iamRoleStatements` section.

> __environments.yml:

```
dev:
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: 'Allow'
      Action: 'execute-api:Invoke'
      Resource: '*'
```

> custom.yml:

```
provider:
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Action:
        - lambda:InvokeFunction
      Resource:
        - "*"
```

Individually, each of them works great. But when I try to run `sls deploy` with both of them, I encounter the following error:

> iamRoleStatements should be an array of objects, where each object has Effect, Action / NotAction, Resource / NotResource fields. Specifically, statement 0 is missing the following properties: Effect, Action / NotAction, Resource / NotResource; statement 1 is missing the following properties: Effect, Action / NotAction, Resource / NotResource

I searched online and this appears to work for other sections of the serverless file such as `resources`:

```
# This works perfectly well.
resources: 
  - ${file(custom.yml):resources, ''}
  - ${file(__environments.yml):resources, ''}
```

So I wonder if there is any solution to this or if it is something that is not currently supported by the Serverless Framework.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You're going to have to jump through a few hoops to get there.

## File Merge Limitations

The serverless framework allows file imports anywhere in the configuration but [only merges `resources` and `functions`](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/blob/master/lib/classes/Service.js#L158) sections.

Your example:

```
provider:
  iamRoleStatements: 
    - ${file(__environments.yml):dev.iamRoleStatements, ''}
    - ${file(custom.yml):provider.iamRoleStatements, ''}
```

Results in an array of arrays like this:

```
{
  "provider": {
    "iamRoleStatements": [
      [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": "execute-api:Invoke",
          "Resource": "*"
        }
      ],
      [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
            "lambda:InvokeFunction"
          ],
          "Resource": [
            "*"
          ]
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

You might be able to submit a very small pull request to rectify this.

## IAM Managed Policies using References

It might be possible to define each of your IAM roles as custom resources, and use the [`iamManagedPolicies` provider config](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam#the-default-iam-role) to point to each of those resources. Something like:

```
provider:
    name: aws
    iamManagedPolicies:
        - Ref: DevIamRole
        - Ref: CustomIamRole

resources:
    - ${file(__environments.yml):resources, ''}
    - ${file(custom.yml):resources, ''}
```

Of course you'd need to change the structure of those two files to be `AWS::IAM::Role` resources.

## Custom IAM Role

The framework also gives you the option to take complete control, which is [fully documented](https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/iam#custom-iam-roles).

I hope this helps.