# providing array of objects (or mapping of sequences) in a yaml file as IAM role definition errors out

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, amazon-iam, serverless-framework

I am using serverless framework to define a new Lambda in an existing stack. To keep with the least privileges principal and my main serevrless.yml file cleaner I am trying to provide the permissions in a separate yaml file for each function (with the "serverless-iam-roles-per-function" plugin). This worked well up until now, when each function required some actions on a single resource. But now I am trying to provide a function with permissions to SQS and SES and I am getting the following error when trying to deploy:

*iamRoleStatements should be an array of objects, where each object has Effect, Action / NotAction, Resource / NotResource fields. Specifically, statement 0 is missing the following properties: Effect, Action / NotAction, Resource / NotResource*

serverless.yml:

```
sendSupportMessage:
    handler: src/handlers/sendSupportMessage.handler
    maximumEventAge: 60
    maximumRetryAttempts: 1
    iamRoleStatements:
      - ${file(iam/sendSupportMessageIAM.yml):sendSupportMessageIAM}
    events:
      - sqs:
          arn: ${self:custom.SupportMessagesQueue.arn}
          batchSize: 1
```

sendSupportMessageIAM.yml:

```
sendSupportMessageIAM:
  - Effect: Allow
    Action:
      - sqs:ReceiveMessage
    Resource: ${self:custom.SupportMessagesQueue.arn}
  - Effect: Allow
    Action:
      - ses:SendEmail
    Resource: arn:aws:ses:*
```

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60640954/serverless-how-to-add-multiple-files-to-iamrolestatements) is similar issue. Have you seen it?

Comment: I did, but to the best of my understanding (I'm still new to serverless framework) it's not the same issue. OP in the linked issue is trying to merge two files while I am providing a single file with permissions for different resources. 

To clarify, if I just put the required permissions in the main serverless.yml file under the function defintion - it works. If I try to import the same from the sendSupportMessageIAM.yml it errors out...